# why my failure toast appears continuously in androi kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, toast

I don't know how to make my failure toast message to show only once.

Toast.makeText(this, vm.logInResult.value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

```
private fun addData(edtTxt: String, pasTxt: String) {
    val repository = UserRepository()
    val viewModelFactory = UserViewModelFactory(repository)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.pushUser(edtTxt, pasTxt)
    viewModel.userPush.observe(this, Observer { response ->
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            dismissLogoProgressDialog()
            Log.d("MainResponse", response.body().toString())
            Log.d("MainExecute", response.code().toString())
            Log.d("Main", response.message())
            val check = response.body()
            Log.d("checkdata", "" + check?.userinfo?.email)
            val tokn: String = check!!.token
            if (sharedPreference.getValueString("token") != null) {
                sharedPreference.clearSharedPreference()
            }
            sharedPreference.save("token", tokn)
            sharedPreference.save("login_uid", check.userinfo.uid)
            sharedPreference.save("change_pass", pasTxt)
            println(check)
            startActivity(Intent(this, DashboardActivity::class.java))
            finish()

        } else {
            dismissLogoProgressDialog()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password mismatch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question and show where this function is called?

Comment: Kindly please check it that updated one

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you only call this `Toast` once? Or is this `Toast` created in a loop? In that case; you need to breakout of the loop first.

Comment: Created in a loop

Answer (score 0):

The function may have been placed within a loop and the else clause is may always be taken.

Are the Log functions printing anything to the console?

Is there anyway you could edit the question and show us where this function is called?